# Finding Dice Probability

Tags: python, for-loop, random

Here is my current code:

```
import random

rolls = 1000  # Set number of rolls here.
num_dice = 2    # Set Number of Dice here.
dice_list = []

for i in range(rolls):
    dice = sum([random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice)])
    dice_list.append(dice)

for i in range(num_dice, (num_dice * 6)+1):
    count = dice_list.count(i)
    count = float(count)
    print("Number of {}'s rolled: {} Probability: {}%".format(i,count, round((count / rolls) * 100),2))
```

My problem is when calculating the percentage of i, it returns the all percentage as 0%.

Update: As I was going through StackOverflow, I've found out why it was returning the percentage to 0%. To get the actual percentage, you need the "count" variable as a decimal form.

Comment: If you rolled 126 8s, you percentage would be `126/1000` which is `0.126` or 12.6%. You care calculating `126/(1000 * 100)` which is `126/100000`, which is wrong. You just have parenthesis in the wrong place. You probably want `(count / rolls) * 100`

Comment: Your "update" is totally incorrect.  It's perfectly OK to have `count` as an integer variable, and casting it to `float` as you did is totally unnecessary since Python 3.

Comment: P.S. `sum` works with a generator as easily as it does a list, so your brackets are redundant: `sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice))`.

Comment: P.P.S.  If you're still using a version of Python 2, you need to specify that in your question.  Python 2.7 became [officially unsupported as of January 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) and it is unreasonable for us to assume it when you're asking a question.

Comment: Hi @MarkRansom. The platform that I'm using is Pycharm CE (Python 2.7)

Comment: The last edit you did totally invalidated the correct answers you got.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong it should be `(count / rolls) * 100`. This seems to not output `0`. But, I just graduated kindergarten, so don't take my word.

```
import random

rolls = 1000  # Set number of rolls here.
num_dice = 2    # Set Number of Dice here.
dice_list = []

for i in range(rolls):
    dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice)]
    x = sum(dice)
    dice_list.append(x)

for i in range(num_dice, (num_dice * 6)+1):
    count = dice_list.count(i)
    print(f"Number of {i}'s rolled: {count} Probability: {round((count / rolls)*100,2)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import random

rolls = 1000  # Set number of rolls here.
num_dice = 2    # Set Number of Dice here.
dice_list = []

for i in range(rolls):
    dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice)]
    x = sum(dice)
    dice_list.append(x)

for i in range(num_dice, (num_dice * 6)+1):
    count = dice_list.count(i)
    print("Number of {}'s rolled: {} Probability: {}%".format(i, count, round(count/rolls*100,2)))
```

Output

```
Number of 2's rolled: 37 Probability: 3.7%
Number of 3's rolled: 57 Probability: 5.7%
Number of 4's rolled: 78 Probability: 7.8%
Number of 5's rolled: 114 Probability: 11.4%
Number of 6's rolled: 145 Probability: 14.5%
Number of 7's rolled: 160 Probability: 16.0%
Number of 8's rolled: 129 Probability: 12.9%
Number of 9's rolled: 123 Probability: 12.3%
Number of 10's rolled: 80 Probability: 8.0%
Number of 11's rolled: 50 Probability: 5.0%
Number of 12's rolled: 27 Probability: 2.7%
```

Comment: Besides the answer, do explain what you did so that OP understand where the issue was.

Comment: hi @Ank, I have updated the calculation `round(count / (rolls * 100)),2` to become `round(count/rolls*100,2)`

Comment: I've updated my code. You need the "count" as a decimal form (float(count)).

Comment: @CalebMurnan have you tried your updated code?  It still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I've updated the code. I needed to have the count as a new variable for float(count).

Comment: @CalebMurnan don't correct the code in the question so it doesn't show your problem anymore, that's totally unfair to those that answered and useless to those who see your question in the future.

Comment: hi @CalebMurnan, your newly edited code `round((count / rolls) * 100),2)` gets output `(3, 2)`, whereas you meant to do `round(count/rolls*100,2)` output `3.4`